# SIM 808 send JSON data with HTTP POST

Tags: at-command

I'm trying to send some data in json format to my server which only accepts http POST request. I have tried the code below.

```
AT
AT+CREG? 
AT+CGATT?
AT+CIPSHUT
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPMUX=0 
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","mtnirancell"
AT+CSTT="mtnirancell","",""
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPSTART= "TCP","(host)","8080"
AT+CIPSEND
>
POST http://(host):8080/api/v1/$ACCESS_TOKEN/telemetry HTTP/1.1 (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
HOST: (host) (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Accept: application/json (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
Content-Type: application/json (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
{(json data)} (Ctrl+M + Ctrl+J)
(ctrl+j)(ctrl+z)
```

The problem is that it keeps saying SIM 808 R14.18 ERROR in the last 4 lines. Also it closes the connection and says CLOSED.

In fact, I used this php code which works pretty well. I just want an equivalent of this code in the SIM 808 Module.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$url = "http://(host):8080/api/v1/$ACCESS_TOKEN/telemetry";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:         application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
?>
</body>
</html>
```